# Better way of writing exceptions - java

Tags: java, exception, java-8

I am reviewing the following code written by a fellow developer. I am not an java expert but IMHO i did not feel this is efficient use of exceptions - the reason i feel so is:

- The below code throwing exception -  seems like flow control. Since we are just using it add a attribute error attribute to PageErrorRequestAttrUtil class - would this be better done using a method instead of throwing a exception for readability.
- The below code is not really defining a API that it is actually expected to throw exception informing the caller something went wrong.

I wanted a second opinion to make sure i am interpreting this incorrectly.

The first class below is invoked in context of AEM/Sightly [1] and returns a java backed object for front end code. In this example the class is checking if a AEM page has certain attributes set and second class is adaptable of request and is used to display helpful messages to the user/author of the page what is missing.

[1] https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/aem/6-1/ref/javadoc/com/adobe/cq/sightly/WCMUsePojo.html

**Class 1**

```
    public class HrefLangUtil extends WCMUsePojo {
        private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HrefLangUtil.class);

        private String hrefLangMultiLine;
        private List<Map> hrefLangMapList;
        private String err;

        final private String COMMA = ",";
        final private String NEW_LINE = "\\n";
        final private static String validUrlCharRegex = "[\\w\\Q!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\\E]+";
        final private String ERROR_MESSAGE = "The following authored hreflang path and code value pair is invalid: ";
        final private String HREF_LANG_MULTI_LINE = "hrefLangMultiLine";
        final private String HREF_LANG_ERROR_MESSAGE = "hrefLangErrorMessage";
        final private String HREF_LANG_PATH = "hrefLangPath";
        final private String HREF_LANG_CODE = "hrefLangCode";

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public void activate() throws Exception {
            ValueMap pageProperties = getPageProperties();
            hrefLangMultiLine = pageProperties.get(HREF_LANG_MULTI_LINE, StringUtils.EMPTY);
            if(!hrefLangMultiLine.isEmpty()){
                String[] hrefLangLine = hrefLangMultiLine.split(NEW_LINE);
                hrefLangMapList = new ArrayList<>();

                try{
                    for (String hrefLang : hrefLangLine ){
                        if(!hrefLang.contains(COMMA) || hrefLang.split(COMMA).length > 2 || !hrefLang.matches(validUrlCharRegex)){
                            throw new Exception(ERROR_MESSAGE + hrefLang);
                        }
                        Map<String, String> hrefLangMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hrefLangMap.put(HREF_LANG_PATH, hrefLang.split(COMMA)[0]);
                        hrefLangMap.put(HREF_LANG_CODE, hrefLang.split(COMMA)[1]);
                        hrefLangMapList.add(hrefLangMap);
                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    err = e.getMessage();
                    log.error(err);
                    SlingHttpServletRequest request = getRequest();
                    RequestAttr requestAttr = new RequestAttr(request);
                    PageErrorRequestAttrUtil.putPageErrorAttr(HREF_LANG_ERROR_MESSAGE, err, requestAttr);
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Map> getHrefLangMapList() {
            return hrefLangMapList;
        }

        public String getErr() {
            return err;
        }
    }
```

**2. Class2**

```
            public class PageErrorRequestAttrUtil{
                  static String PAGE_LEVEL_ERROR_MESSAGES = "pageLevelErrorMessages";
                  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PageErrorRequestAttrUtil.class);

                /**
                 * @param key The key which describes the origin of the error or alert
                 * @param value The actual error message which will be displayed at the top of the page. Should be passed as a {@link String}.
                 * @param requestAttr The object representation {@link RequestAttr} of the the current request
                 * @return String
                 */
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                public static Object putPageErrorAttr(String key, Object value, RequestAttr requestAttr){
                    try{
                        Map<Object, Object> pageLevelErrorMessages;
                        if(!requestAttr.containsKey(key)){
                            pageLevelErrorMessages = new HashMap<>();
                            pageLevelErrorMessages.put(key, value);
                            requestAttr.put(PAGE_LEVEL_ERROR_MESSAGES, pageLevelErrorMessages);
                        }else{
                            if(requestAttr.get(PAGE_LEVEL_ERROR_MESSAGES) instanceof Map){
                                pageLevelErrorMessages = (Map) requestAttr.get(PAGE_LEVEL_ERROR_MESSAGES);
                                pageLevelErrorMessages.put(key, value);
                                requestAttr.put(key, pageLevelErrorMessages);
                            } else{
                                throw new Exception();
                            }
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        log.error("The expected pageLevelErrorMessages Map is a reserved key for error messages, it is not of the expected type, Map<>");
                    }
                    return value;
                }
        }
```

Please suggest

Comment: I don't like either of them. The error logging should take place inside the block where it is detected. There shouldn't be any throws here at all.

Comment: Using exceptions for flow control is _extremely_ bad practice.  Exceptions are intended for exceptional conditions, and are very expensive to create.  I've had to clean up code like this before.

Answer (score 0):

[codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for this.

Coming to your questions,

> The below code is not really defining a API that it is actually expected to throw exception informing the caller something went wrong.

`activate` as a method is expected to perform some action, and it can throw an exception when it can't. It would have been a different story had the method been `canActivate`

> The below code throwing exception - seems like flow control. Since we are just using it add a attribute error attribute to PageErrorRequestAttrUtil class - would this be better done using a method instead of throwing a exception for readability.

Agree with you. The above code can be replaced with a simple `if...else`